# Google analytics test for the In-Page Analytics error

Tags: google-analytics

I am getting following error whenever i test the In-Pageanalytics form my google analytic account.

I have added the new version of google analytics js, provided by google.

Please let me know anybody faced the same problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. When I looked closer at that, debug told told me that there is an error in inpage.js file

Comment: It might be helpful if you paste the given error. As it is, this should be a comment not an answer.